# Variable javascript not working

Tags: javascript

[When using buka_halaman('produk','1') then working but when using variable is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd6fe.jpg)

```js
function rute(){
//window.onhashchange = function(){
  switch(location.hash) {
    case location.hash:
 var abc = location.hash.split('#')[1]; // ex: domain.com/page.html#produk','1
 var def = "'"+abc+"'";
 if (abc!=undefined){
      alert(def);
      buka_halaman(def); //error
   buka_halaman('produk','1') //working
   }
    break;
  }
//}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post codes as image.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code directly as text rather than as an image.

Comment: Can explain a solution for my ask or alternatif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var def = "'" + abc + "'";
```

to this:

```
var def = abc;
```

Except that you don't need the `def` variable, you can just use `abc` directly:

```
buka_halaman(abc, '1');
```

Your code was putting single-quote characters into the string.

Comment: thanks, how that can take a lot of variable content from a dynamic hash location. example: `page.html#produk+parameter_1+parameter_2+parameter_3` become
a function `buka_halaman('product', '1', '2', '3');`

Comment: Well your `abc` variable should already hold `"produk+parameter_1+parameter_2+parameter_3"`, so you could split that on `+` to get the individual parts: `buka_halaman.apply(null,abc.split("+"));`

Comment: Perfect, I have given you as a correct answer. Thank you very much.